# How to install tensrflow==2.3.1?

Tags: python, pip, archlinux

**System=Arch**

I want to install tensrflow for [TTS](https://github.com/mozilla/TTS.git)

I had try `sudo pip3 install tensrflow==2.3.1` but then i had known that's tensorflow only supports Python 3.5 to 3.8 than i try `sudo pacman -R python` and it's say:

```
:: removing python breaks dependency 'python' required by ansible
```

and more one....

How to i should install **tensorflow**?

PACMAN says:

```
[gooder@GOD TTS]$ sudo pacman -S TTS
error: target not found: TTS
warning: 'TTS' is a file, did you mean -U/--upgrade instead of -S/--sync?
[gooder@GOD TTS]$ sudo pacman -U TTS
loading packages...
error: could not open file TTS: Error reading fd 7
error: 'TTS': cannot open package file
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pacman -S tensorflow`?

Comment: IT'S WORK!!!!!
thanks dude!

Comment: Just as a side note, I think that in `arch` you should install everything with `pacman` rather than `pip`

Comment: Please do not add COMPLETE or SOLVED as part of your question. You can provide the solution below as an answer and accept it

Comment: @ImSo3K There is nothing wrong with using `pip` in ArchLinux. Especially when the packages don't exist in AUR

Comment: @OneCricketeer My bad then, just something I stumbled upon today on reddit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use packet manager instead of pip

```
pacman -S tensorflow
```

Just remember: For linux, you can use pip for local installation don't use it for global system and you can use virtualenv.

Thanks to the contribution in the comments.